# Is there a simple way to add street view to my Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Basically I just want to add street view to my existing maps, changing the side bar from this:

```
http://snpr.cm/BdJy9z.png
```

To this:

```
http://snpr.cm/4Wz4EZ.png
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was still on Google Maps API v2, with v3 street view is there automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of documentation for the google map api. You should read it.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetView

Here's an example:

```
var panoramaOptions = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);,
  pov: {
    heading: 34,
    pitch: 10,
    zoom: 1
  }
};
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"),panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
```